# Facebook Page Tab Not Showing

Tags: facebook

Whats up guys,

So i'm trying to add a Tab to my facebook page, i followed all the instructions on developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

But when i click on the tab, it's not displaying anything. At first i thought it may have been the link so i tested it with paypal and it still shows up blank. I added it as a canvas and a page tab.

Here's the link: https://www.facebook.com/PersiaGrai/app/481278078749813/?ref=page_internal

Does anyone know where i may have went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook loads apps into the iframe by submitting a hidden form with method=post.

Your URL answers o.k., if it is requested via GET – but for a POST request, it simply answers with a 404 Not Found. (So you will need to go investigate why now.)